# std::move with vector<unique_ptr> object literal not compiling but push_back(move) does

Tags: c++, stdvector, move-semantics, initializer-list

I am having a hard time understanding why `std::move()` with object literals doesn't work.

Given the following simple code:

```cpp
#include <memory> 
#include  <vector>

class A{
};

void func(A &&param1){
}

int main()
{
    auto a = std::unique_ptr<A>(new A());
    auto vec = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>{std::move(a)};   //this code does not work!!
    //std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vec;    // but this code works
    //vec.push_back(std::move(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Since C++20, `push_back()` is defined as `constexpr`:

```cpp
constexpr void push_back( T&& value );
```

Shouldn't `std::move()` work the same in both object literal vector initialization and using `push_back()`?

Comment: You can move into an initializer_list - the `{}` part - but not move out of it.

Comment: "*Since C++20, `push_back()` is defined as `constexpr`*" - being `constexpr` just means that it is potentially callable at compile-time, but everything you have shown runs at runtime only. That being said, `push_back()` has supported move semantics since C++11. And on a side note, since C++14, use `std::make_unique()` instead of constructing `std::unique_ptr` directly: `auto a = std::make_unique<A>();`